# Validating slightly differing urls to a database

Tags: javascript, web, url

I am building an internal tool for our team, which is basically a database of urls.
Within a Chrome extension I want to be able to check whether the url the user is currently on is in our database.

Checking this for the main domains is easy. The problem is that often query parameters differ slightly. For example, in a sharepoint link, the query paramter `sourcedoc` indicates the document ID, while the query paramter `mobileredirect` is not necessary, since I get on the same page with or without this parameter.

So when I parce an url, is there any standard way/algorithm to check whether parts of the url/query parameters are optional or unimportant?

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to _determine_ that the `mobileredirect` parameter in your example was optional? That could only be done by requesting the content both those two different URLs return, and comparing it ...

Comment: This is not possible to do automatically – only if you know how the site works, i.e. a query param might be important for loading a page, e.g. ?pageId=1

Comment: how about using a validation middleware?

Answer (score 1):

No,

Typically query parameters that aren't recognized are ignored. There's no protocol to determine in advance what query parameters may be used.

There's some databases that strip out common tracking query parameters, but that's just a list of parameters that's safe to ignore.

The only way some sites *may* communicate that a specific url+queryparameter variation is the same as another, is if they include a `canonical` link header or HTML element.

For those cases it basically lets you find the 'one true URL' for a given url, which is what search engines use to de-duplicate. Using that link is optional though.

```
Link: </foo>; rel="canonical"
```

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="/foo" />
```